# Disable GPS using dialog box (Android)

Tags: android, gps, android-gps

Applications like Google Maps show dialog box to enable GPS.

Is it possible to make an application which shows such dialog box to disable GPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't directly try to enable/disable gps, rather, the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html) suggests your app to specify the required level of accuracy/power consumption and desired update interval, and the device automatically makes the appropriate changes to system settings.

I'll add the code from the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html#prompt) here for immediate reference,

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
// ...
SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
        // location requests here.
        // ...
    }
});

task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
            // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
            // by showing the user a dialog.
            try {
                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                        REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                // Ignore the error.
            }
        }
    }
});
```